# mysql sort order is not returning the values I require

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have a table called employee, I wish to arrange this table by numbers i.e the lowest number (1) will be sorted first and the highest number (20) last.

I accordingly added a column to the table:

```
ADD COLUMN  sort_order INT DEFAULT 0
```

The problem that I am encountering is that the '0 or empty fields' in the table are sorted before the actual number.

Can someone please advise me what I need to do to avoid the default value of 0 from going first; i.e, is there another default value that I can use.

Comment: Not sure about mysql, but in oracle, you could omit the default (so the column will be NULL if nothing is given), then use `order by sort_order nulls last`. Of course, you could use 99999 as default as well, then do something in your output code to prevent the 99999 from being printed.

Comment: At business logic level, what's the difference between `0` and `NULL`?

Comment: @andreea115 - what is the use of that column?

Comment: fathah rehman: the use of the column is only for sorting out the results. the user will have the ability to allocate a number to each column: according to which numbers they wish to allocate first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make `0` go last by ordering by `sort_order=0, sort_order`.

`sort_order=0` will have the value 1 if `sort_order=0` and 0 otherwise, so sorting by that first will make the 0 values go last.

```
SELECT ... ORDER BY sort_order=0, sort_order
```

Comment: can you please explain the logic, i am a bit confused, your query is running fine, I was trying to understand the logic, that if sort_order=0 then it should show it first in the result, how it is coming last.

Comment: @Deepika The comparison `sort_order=0` will have the value `1` if it's true (ie sort_order equals 0), and `0` otherwise. Since `0` sorts before `1`, rows where `sort_order` is not equal to zero will sort before rows where `sort_order=0`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation it will be really helpful, this option is better than using case

Comment: i still dont understand the explanation of why this work . can sombody please explain why this works.

Comment: @andreea115 Equals `=` in this case will compare two values and return 1 if the sides are equal or 0 otherwise. In other words, `5=5` will have the value 1, and `5=4` will have the value 0. Since we order by `sort_order=0`, the rows where the sides are equal (sort_order is equal to 0) will have the value 1, and where they're not equal will have the value 0. When we order by it, 0 will order before 1, so rows where sort_order is not equal to 0 (value 0) will sort before the rows where sort_order is equal to 0 (value 1). Make sense? :)

Comment: wow. totally clear. wow. i am glad i picked up the courage and admitted that i did not understand; i now totally understood how you did it. thank you; i learnt something new today!

Answer (score 2):

This will put rows where sort_order is null or is 0 at the bottom:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
ORDER BY
  sort_order IS NULL OR sort_order=0,
  sort_order
```

because `sort_order IS NULL OR sort_order=0` will be evaluated to 0 when it's false, and 1 when it's true.

Answer (score 0):

Both the already answered answers are correct and will give you the same result, besides that you can also use the following query

```
select * from Table1 order by 
case when sortorder = 0 then 1 else 0 end, sortorder ASC
```

demo at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/95dcd/10